# How to Create Spring WebSocket Application With HTML5 WebSocket API?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-websocket

Recent Version of **Spring WebSocket** works with **SockJS** and **StompJS** libraries. **But i don't like to use theme in my application**. So how to create Spring WebSocket application with [**HTML5 WebSocket API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)   and integrate our application with **Spring Security**?

Answer (score 4):

I could not find any good example on how to configure spring websocket without sockjs but i found some helpful [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket-server) in spring documentation site and i like to share that. **Well, How to Create Spring WebSocket Application With HTML5 WebSocket API?**

**First:** Create a **Class** that **extends** **TextWebSocketHandler** or **BinaryWebSocketHandler** and Annotate it with **@Component** annotation and **Override** its appropriate method.This **Class** works like handler methods in controllers.

```
@Component
public class SimpleWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, 
            TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        // Sends back response to client.
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Connection is all right."));
    }
}
```

**Second:** Create a **Configuration Class** that **implements WebSocketConfigurer** and Annotate it with **@Configuration** and **@EnableWebSocket** annoations and **Override** its appropriate method.This **Class** uses **Handler Class** that we created already.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfigurations implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private SimpleWebSocketHandler simpleWebSocketHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // Regsiters a handler for related endpoint.
        registry.addHandler(simpleWebSocketHandler, "/chat");
    }
}
```

**Third:** Add all your **WebSokcet Endpoints** to your **Spring Security Configuration**.

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/chat").permitAll();
```

**Fourth:** We create a new **javascript WebSocket objet** with appropriate **URL**.

```
// Create WebSocket Object.
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat");

// Runs when connecion is estabilished.
ws.onopen = function () {
    // Sends request to server with string value.
    ws.send("webSocket");
};

// Runs when response is ready.
// Use event to get response value.
ws.onmessage = function (event) {

};
```

**Note: WebSocket URLs Format: `ws://domain:port/endpoint`**

Comment: thank you, but I can use spring websocket only after
        registry.addHandler(simpleWebSocketHandler, "/chat").setAllowedOrigins("*");
otherwise I get 302 or 403 errors. Spring Security Configuration does not really helps in my case.